# How to group several output variables together in Theano?

Tags: python, numerical-methods, theano

I am trying to implement a function in Theano that maps a vector to a vector, but each dimension of the output vector is specified by hand. If I create a Theano function like so:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
x = T.dvector('x')
dx = 28.0 * (x[1] - x[0])
dy = x[0] * (10.0 - x[1]) - x[2]
dz = x[0] * x[1] - 8.0/3/0 * x[2]
f = theano.function([x],[dx,dy,dz])
```

then `f([1,2,3])` gives `[array(10.0), array(23.0), array(-6.0)]` as the output, when I'd like it to return `array([10.0, 23.0, -6.0])`. What is the Theanic way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

The other answer by Kyle Kastner will work, but you can have Theano do that for you (I fixed the division by 0 from your example):

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
x = T.dvector('x')
dx = 28.0 * (x[1] - x[0])
dy = x[0] * (10.0 - x[1]) - x[2]
dz = x[0] * x[1] - 8.0/3.0 * x[2]
o = T.as_tensor_variable([dx,dy,dz])
f = theano.function([x],o)
f([1,2,3])
# output array([ 28.,   5.,  -6.])
```

Comment: This looks cool. Am I missing something or did you post code that does the same thing twice? :) - The docstring says that the function 'does something sensible' with the input. I haven't had the chance to try with arrays that are say hstackable and arrays that are of completely different shape. What is the sensible thing that it does here?

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the duplicate code. I don't understand your question in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the function is just a list of numpy arrays - you can do `np.array(f([1, 2, 3]))` to convert the output list into a numpy vector.